# How to use Property inside Method in C#

Tags: c#, oop

How to use Property inside method in right way. I was searching on the internet but I can't found property is used inside method that will be returned value.

```
 public class OET
{


    public int ShiftTime { get; set; }
    public int BreakTime { get; set; }
    public int DownTime { get; set; }
    public int ProductionTarget { get; set; }

    public int IdealRunRate { get; set; }
    public int PrductionOneShift { get; set; }
    public int RejectedProduct { get; set; }

    public int planedProductionTime(int shift, int breaktime) {

        shift = ShiftTime;
        breaktime = BreakTime;

        return shift - breaktime;

    }
```

I would like to use property to get value from "PlanedProductionTIme" method, is it code above right?

Comment: [Msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).

Comment: Just use "return this.ShiftTime - this.BreakTime;" there is no need for your parameters (shift, breaktime).

Comment: there is no use of "sift" and "breaktime" local variable into is function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example isn't very clear, because you're passing in two parameters, but then ignoring them in your calculation. But if your intention was to have a property returning the calculated PlannedProductionTime, it can go like this:

```
public int PlannedProductionTime
{
    get { return ShiftTime - BreakTime; }
}
```

Note that this is *instead* of the method - a property is a syntactic way to have a method accessed like a property:

OET myOet = new OET();
   int plannedProductionTime = myOet.PlannedProductionTime;

Answer (score 0):

there is no use of "sift" and "breaktime" local variable into is function. just use return ShiftTime-BreakTime.

```
public int method2() {
///here you are getting the peroperties value and doing calculations returns result.
    return ShiftTime -BreakTime;

}
```

if your requirement is to set the properties value.

```
 public void method1(int shift, int breaktime) {

      ShiftTime=  shift ;
     BreakTime  = breaktime;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int PlanedProductionTime { get { return ShiftTime - BreakTime; } }
```

You can define the property as a calculated ones, by defining the get method in it.

More solutions - you can define a separate function and call it inside get. It will help if you want to do some more complex calculations which needs to be used somewhere else in the class - private or outside class - public.

```
public int PlanedProductionTime { get { return _calculatePlannedProductionTime( ShiftTime, BreakTime); } }

private\public int _calculatePlannedProductionTime (int shift, int break)
{
 return shift - break;
}
```